# Out of stack space in Internet explorer 11 for angular app when integrated into a PEGA app

Tags: javascript, angular, internet-explorer-11, integration

I am trying to integrate my application which is build in angular 7 with other application build in Pega technology. I am using an external js file and loading all required js file like main.js,script.js,polyfills.js and vendor.js in it and trying to bootstrap our application from that external js file.

In Chrome and Safari its working really good but when I try to run my application in IE , its throwing error saying Out of Stack space error polyfills.js or some other js file from the application.

Our polyfill ts file looks like below

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es7/array';


import 'core-js/es6/array';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG 
elements */
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';


import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.

Tsconfig file looks like below:
{
"compileOnSave": false,
"compilerOptions": {
"baseUrl": "./",
"outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
"sourceMap": true,
"declaration": false,
"module": "es2015",
//"module": "esnext",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"importHelpers": true,
"target": "es5",
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types"
],
"lib": [
  "es2018",
  "dom"
]
}
}

External js look like below:
$(document).ready(function () {
var scriptPolyfills;
var scriptMain;
var scriptRuntime;
var scriptStyles;
var scriptEsPolyfill;
var scriptVendor;
setTimeout(function() {

    scriptPolyfills = document.createElement('script');
    scriptPolyfills.type = 'text/javascript';
    scriptPolyfills.src = '../../polyfills.js';

    scriptEsPolyfill = document.createElement('script');
    scriptEsPolyfill.type = 'text/javascript';
    scriptEsPolyfill.src = '../../es2015-polyfills.js';

    scriptMain = document.createElement('script');
    scriptMain.type = 'text/javascript';
    scriptMain.async = "true";
    scriptMain.src = '../../main.js';

    scriptRuntime = document.createElement('script');
    scriptRuntime.type = 'text/javascript';
    scriptRuntime.async = "true";
    scriptRuntime.src = '../../runtime.js';


    scriptStyles = document.createElement('script');
    scriptStyles.type = 'text/javascript';
    scriptStyles.src = '../../styles.js';

    scriptVendor = document.createElement('script');
    scriptVendor.type = 'text/javascript';
    scriptVendor.async = "true";
    scriptVendor.src = '../../vendor.js';

    var appRoot = document.createElement('app-root');
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id='benefitSearch';
    //div.appendChild(scriptpolyfillLoad);
    div.appendChild(scriptMain);
    div.appendChild(scriptRuntime);
    div.appendChild(scriptPolyfills);
    div.appendChild(scriptEsPolyfill);
    div.appendChild(scriptStyles);
    div.appendChild(scriptVendor);
    div.appendChild(appRoot);
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    $(div).insertAfter( $("#pzFlowActionUITypeRef"));
},8000);
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Based on my searching result, It looks like polyfil related issue.

Try to add below polyfil may help to solve this error.

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';  
import 'core-js/es6/object';  
import 'core-js/es6/function';  
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';  
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';  
import 'core-js/es6/number';  
import 'core-js/es6/math';  
import 'core-js/es6/string';  
import 'core-js/es6/date';  
import 'core-js/es6/array';  
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';  

if (WeakMap.toString().indexOf('function WeakMap()') === -1) {  
    WeakMap = undefined;  
}  
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';  
// Check for native support of Map vs Polyfill  
if (Map.toString().indexOf('function Map()') === -1) {  
    Map = undefined;  
}  
import 'core-js/es6/map';  
// Check for native support of Map vs Polyfill  
if (Set.toString().indexOf('function Set()') === -1) {  
    Set = undefined;  
}  
import 'core-js/es6/set';  
export class Polyfills {  
}
```

Reference:

(1) [How To Fix "Out Of Stack Space" Issue While Running Angular SPFx WebPart In IE11](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-fix-out-of-stack-space-issue-while-run-angular-spfx-webpart-in-ie11/)

(2) ["Out of stack space" in IE #316](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/316)

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your response.I tried adding polyfil suggested by you. It gave me another error saying "Promise is undefined" in Vendor.js. To resolve Promise is undefined error , I tried installing promise with command-" npm install promise-polyfill --save-exact
" and added it in App module as import 'promise-polyfill/src/polyfill'; then I still got same Out of Stack space error.

Comment: Try to refer this article may help to run your Angular app with Internet Explorer. Ref: https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-and-internet-explorer-5e59bb6fb4e9

Comment: Unfortunately, this is won't help. I agree that polyfills might be the right way to fix it.